# C++ application: Is it possible to pass accepted TCP connection from one process to another?

Tags: c++, tcp, connection, interprocess

So I wonder - is it possible to pass accepted TCP connection (on Windows or Unix like OS) from one process to another? Here the point is to pass connection - not data in a way a proxy app would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, use [`WSADuplicateSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741565%28VS.85%29.aspx), pass the filled in [`WSAPROTOCOL_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741675%28VS.85%29.aspx) to the other process, use [`WSPSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to recreate a socket.

On unix-like OS'es this is possible using the `sendmsg()` system call. [libancillary](http://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/) abstracts this for you.

Comment: Is there any library that is alike libancillary for windows? and are out there any code samples / examples on how to do such thing on windows?

Comment: Don't know of any library - The only time I had to do this I just wrote it from scratch. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: So.. I tried to create a sample using Boost.ASIO and Windows WSADuplicateSocket... Currently at least inside one process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326564/c-boost-asio-passing-accepted-tcp-connection-from-one-opened-socket-to-another may be you could posibly take a look and provide any help? Pleeease)

Answer (score 8):

In Unix, a TCP connection is represented as a socket file descriptor. When you `fork` a process, the file descriptors are inherited by the child process, including TCP sockets. (Though they may be closed on `exec` if given the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag with [`fcntl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html).)

It's also possible to transfer file descriptors between unrelated processes using a local (Unix) domain socket; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489433/sending-file-descriptor-over-unix-domain-socket-and-select).

I'm not sure about Windows.

Comment: what does it mean? that two processes will share same connection?

Comment: @Andrey: yes, so they must co-ordinate their access to the connection.

Comment: @Andry - A socket is just a file descriptor. Once you `accept()` a connection, you can do whatever you want with it, including sending it to another local process.

Comment: A socket is not a file descriptor on Windows.