# Is there any cross-platform library for accepted TCP connections interprocess exchange?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, cross-platform, interprocess

Any Boost like ones? Or any other Windows, Mac, Linux library's for passing established TCP connection from one process to another? So I actually [did not even know it is possible but seems it is!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312773/c-application-is-it-possible-to-pass-accepted-tcp-connection-from-one-process) So I defiantly want to use such feature in my server!) And I would love to see any cross-platform lib helping me to do that. Are there any such library's?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, QT provides this functionality!
Read more [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/ipc.html).

Comment: Hm... I love Qt but could you post a link on sharing accepted connections with it or provide a code sample here?

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683665/where-is-boost-process) though it is not yet accepted into Boost.

Comment: Hm.. Could you provide a link that shows an example on how to use 
Boost.Process for such things? (I thought it can only lunch applications with params...)

Comment: @Blender I'm not sure what you mean, the library wrappers `fork`. Is that what you need?

Comment: I need a library suited for passing accepted TCP connection from one process to another.

Comment: @Blender again, I'm not sure what you're asking. Maybe you should edit your question to clarify? File descriptors that do not have their `FD_CLOEXEC` flag set will be inherited by the child process after `fork`.

Comment: @Blender my experience is with Linux, so those are the terms I use. The Boost.Process library wraps the fork system call into a nice interface. Presumably the other supported platforms are similarly wrapped. If you have specific questions, I suggest you ask them separately.