# Linux, C++, will dup(socket) work from another not forked process (if not how to enable it)?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, connection, interprocess

So I opened a socket connection like was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326564/c-boost-asio-passing-accepted-tcp-connection-from-one-opened-socket-to-another) I want to let other processes use that open connection. Will `dup()` help me or what shall I do?

Comment: You mean like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312773/c-application-is-it-possible-to-pass-accepted-tcp-connection-from-one-process/5312831#5312831 ? `dup` isn't going to be helpful here at all.

Comment: yep... but it would be so much cooler to perform that black magic in less than 10 lines...=)

Comment: Just as a side note, the Unix way is to create a socket in a process and then use `fork()`. That child process inherits all the sockets (unless they were opened with `O_CLOEXEC`). That way is really easy in Unix. Much harder in Windows... Each OS has its pros and cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass sockets between existing processes you need to use `sendmsg` - Or [libancillary](http://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/) which abstracts the whole thing.

Comment: ok... so nothing like WSADuplicateSocket on linux out of the box... hm=(